# Looking to build a game that uses names of Premier League teams - what are the steps required to stay compliant

Tags: legal

I am looking to build a game that users would play weekly. In order for the game to make sense, I would have to display the names of the 20 Premier League teams playing on a weekly basis. I will **not be using the names of players** themselves. The game would require people to pay to contend for their share of a weekly pot of winnings.

The game would be similar to: https://fantasy.espn.com/games/english-premier-league-pickem-2020/make-picks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use someone's [intellectual property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property), you need to contact them regarding licensing.

The description of your game essentially sounds like gambling. As such you would also need to check to see if you are compliant with any laws you might be subject to as well as any terms of service with respect to whatever platform you plan to release on.